# How best to develop the sql to support Search functionality in a web application?

Tags: sql

Like many web applications (business) the customer wants a form that will search across each data field.  The form could have 15-20 different fields where the user can select/enter/input to be used in sql (stored procedure).

These are quite typical requests by the user that most every application has to deal with.

The **issue** really at hand is how to provide the user with this type of interface/option **AND** establish fast SQL access.  The above fields could span 15 different tables and respective sql statements (usually abstracted to a stored procedure) will have as many joins.  The data always has to be brought back to a grid type view as well as some report format (often excel).

I/we are finding these sql statements are slow and hard to optimize as the user can enter 1 or 15 different search criteria.

How should this be done? Looking for suggestions/ideas as to how existing large applications deal with these requirements.
Does it really come down to trying to optimize the sql within the stored procedure?

thx

Comment: In addition the application needs to include paging and sorts by any of the fields.

Comment: sounds like you need to check into fulltext searching on your particular database system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to employ a real search engine technology to make fulltext search have good performance.  No SQL predicate (e.g. `LIKE '%pattern%'`) is going to be scalable.

You don't identify which brand of RDBMS you're using, but every major brand of RDBMS has their own fulltext search capability:

- Microsoft SQL Server: [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)
- Oracle: [Oracle Text](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/text/index.html) (formerly ConText)
- MySQL: [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) index (MyISAM only)
- PostgreSQL: [Text-Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) data types and index types
- SQLite: [Full-Text Search](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=FullTextIndex) (FTS)
- IBM DB2: [Text Search](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/dm-dw-dm-0810shettar-i.html)

There are also third-party solutions for indexing text, such as:

- Apache [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) / [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Xapian](http://xapian.org/)